# Terraform dial tcp 192.xx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout error

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, terraform

I am trying to implement CI / CD using GitLab + Terraform to K8S Cluster and K8S Control Plane (Master node) was setup on **CentOS**

However, Pipeline job fails with the following error

```
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Get "https://192.xx.xx.xx/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets?labelSelector=tfstate%3Dtrue": dial tcp 192.xx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout
```

From the error mentioned above (`default/secrets?labelSelector=tfstate%3Dtrue`), I assume the error is related to missing 'terraform secret' on default namespace

**Example (Terraform secret taken from my Windows)**

```
PS C:\> kubectl get secret
NAME                    TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-7mzv6     kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      27d
tfstate-default-state   Opaque                                1      15h
```

However, I am not sure which process would create 'tfsecret' or should we create it manually ?

Kindly let me know if I my understanding is wrong and had I missed anything else

**EDIT**

The issue mentioned above occurred because existing Gitlab-runner was on a different subnet (eg 172.xx.xx.xx instead of 192.xx.xx.xx)

I was asked to use a different Gitlab-runner which runs on the same subnet and now it throws the following error

```
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Get "https://192.xx.xx.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets?labelSelector=tfstate%3Dtrue": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Now, I am bit confused whether the certificate-issue is between `GitLab-Runner and Gitlab-Server` **or** `Gitlab-Server and K8S Cluster` or something else

Comment: the error indicates that it fails to access the apiserver.

Comment: `dial tcp 192.xx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout` is the actual reason for this error, `default/secrets?labelSelector=tfstate%3Dtrue` endpoint is not reachable bacause connection to `192.xx.xx.xx:443` is timing out. Whatever is `192.xx.xx.xx` should be your api-server IP.

Comment: Please include more details about your environment - api-server details, yaml manifests of deployments etc. It will make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Edited my question with updated result

Comment: This seems like a problem with gitlab-runner and/or Terraform. `Failed to get existing workspaces` seems specific to Terraform. You may want to look at [gitlab-runner documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured Kubernetes as the remote state backend for your Terraform configuration. The error is, that the backend is trying to query existing secrets to determine what workspaces are configured. The `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` indicates, that the KUBECONFIG the remote state backend uses does not match the CA of the API server you're connecting to.

If the runners are K8s pods themselves, make sure you provide a KUBECONFIG that matches your target cluster and that the remote state does not configure itself as `in-cluster` by reading the service account token every K8s pod has - which in most cases will only work for the cluster the pod is running on.

You don't provide enough information to be more specific. But big picture, you have to configure the state backend, and any provider that connect to K8s. Theoretically, the state backend secrets and the K8s resources do not have to be on the same cluster. Meaning, you may have to have different configuration for state backend and K8s providers.